# Count of lines in a file in python3

Tags: python-3.x, file

How to print a number of lines edited by an arithmetic operation to a file, please?
Let's say that multiplied by 2, for simplification. I tried:

```
f = open(f'file.dat', 'rw')
it = sum(1 for _ in f)*2
f.write("A  B  C line: \n")
f.write("\n")
f.close()

Desired result:
A  B  C line: 2
A  B  C line: 4
A  B  C line: 6
```

I obtain an error:

```
io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable
```

Comment: You have opened the file for appending, not reading, so ```sum(1 for _ in f)*2``` is invalid.

Comment: I would like to count the lines and then append something. Should I open the file twice?

Comment: or you could open it to rw,  then count the lines, and then write to the end of the file

Comment: I obtained: ValueError: must have exactly one of create/read/write/append mode

Comment: How exactly did you change your code?

Comment: I added it to the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243814/discussion-between-carly-and-ewong).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following:

1. Open the file in r+ mode.
2. read the previous lines and sum the values
3. write a new line to the file.

```
with open("bleh.txt", 'r+') as fp:
    it = sum(1 for _ in fp) * 2
    fp.write("A  B  C  line: %d\n" % it)
```

The problem with this approach is that if the file doesn't exist, it chokes.

So,  change `r+` to `a+`.

So the final code:

```
with open("bleh.txt", "a+") as fp:
    it = sum(1 for _ in fp) * 2
    fp.write("A  B  C  line: %d\n" % it)
```

Of course...  with `a+` mode,  the file pointer is placed at the end of the file.  So.. the following needs to be added:

```
with open("bleh.txt", "a+") as fp:
    fp.seek(0)
    it = sum(1 for _ in fp) * 2
    fp.write("A  B  C  line: %d\n" % it)
```

This moves the file pointer back to the beginning.

Comment: When I run the code more times, I obtain only line: 0, line: 0 ... instead of line: 0, line: 2, line: 4 ....